# Converting daterangepicker to angular directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, daterangepicker

I am trying to wrap a daterangepicker plugin into an angular directive. Although I managed to make it work by alerting the selected dates in the callback function, I cannot seem to either save the selected dates to the $scope or update the ng-model. I added a comment '// CALLBACK of daterangepicker' so that anyone seeing this can locate it easily in the code below. I hope someone with more experience can shed some light on how this can be achieved.

**HTML (calling the directive):**

```
<input id="date-range-picker" class="form-control" type="text"
```

ng-model="date" time-recorder-date-range-picker />

**Angular directive:**

```
module.directive('timeRecorderDateRangePicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            element.daterangepicker({
                startDate: moment.utc().subtract(7, 'days'),
                endDate: moment.utc(),
                minDate: '01/01/2014',
                maxDate: moment.utc(),
                dateLimit: {
                    days: 365
                },
                showDropdowns: false,
                showWeekNumbers: true,
                timePicker: false,
                ranges: {
                    'Today': [moment.utc(), moment.utc()],
                    'Yesterday': [moment.utc().subtract(1, 'days'), moment.utc().subtract(1, 'days')],
                    'Last 7 Days': [moment.utc().subtract(6, 'days'), moment.utc()],
                    'Last 30 Days': [moment.utc().subtract(29, 'days'), moment.utc()],
                    'This Month': [moment.utc().startOf('month'), moment.utc().endOf('month')],
                    'Last Month': [moment.utc().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment.utc().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
                },
                opens: 'right',
                format: 'MMMM D, YYYY',
                separator: ' to ',
                buttonClasses: ['btn btn-default'],
                locale: {
                    applyLabel: 'Apply',
                    cancelLabel: 'Cancel',
                    fromLabel: 'From',
                    toLabel: 'To',
                    customRangeLabel: 'Custom',
                    daysOfWeek: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
                    monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
                    firstDay: 1
                }
            }, function(start, end, label) {
                // CALLBACK of daterangepicker
                alert('Callback!!!');
            }).prev().on('click', function() { // makes calendar icon click work
                $(this).next().focus();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Have a look at the example described at `https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController` to use ngModel on custom directives.

Comment: does anyone has working example of the above question posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  [dangrossman's bootstrap-daterangepicker](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker) in Angularjs project using jqlite, try this

In HTML

```
<input type="text" id="daterange" />
```

Then attach the picker to the element you want to trigger it using jqlite

```
 angular.element('#daterange').daterangepicker({
        timePicker: true,
        timePickerIncrement: 30,
        locale: {
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A'
        }
    });
```

you can also use events

```
    angular.element('#daterange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      //do something, like calling a function
      $scope.doSomething(picker.startDate, picker.endDate);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the datepicker into a directive and enable the model to be updated like this:

```
angular.module('DatePicker', [])
.directive('datepicker', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        element.datepicker({
          format: 'dd/mm/yy',
          onSelect: function(date) {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date),
              scope.$apply();
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
```